# Linux ifcfg network script configuration for RedHat/Fedora/Centos

Tags: networking, centos, linux-networking, ifconfig

I've been a long time Linux user and would like to know where I can find the `ifcfg` network script documentation (interface configuration?) (not just some tutorial; I want official documentation)?

I ask because I am used to using `Network Manager` but in many cases I've had to attempt to use `/etc/network/network-scripts` for network configurations; but I cannot seem to find any official documentation (because I do not know what I am looking for).

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the official documentation from RedHat: http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Reference_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html

There you'll find all the configurable parameters in an Ethernet interface configuration file.